# Can't seem to figure out how to show a value in a list onto a label in tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

Just trying to pick a value in a list and have it print on a label. Can't really find anything on the internet to help me out

Comment: If list name is `lst` then label should be `Label(root,text=lst[0]).pack()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to edit the label, use `.config()` method. Is this what you wanted?

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

def printLabel(index):
    label.config(text=alphabet[index])

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text='None')
label.pack()
root.after(500, lambda: printLabel(randint(0,4)))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you might want to use `root.after(500, lambda: printLabel(randint(1,5)))` have you tried your piece of code before posting it?

Comment: I've tried it, and it works fine, what is the advantage of using lamda?

Comment: It's not an advantage, basically your calling the function when using `()` but since you tried it on I think `after` method does not need `lambda`. But can you just increase the time and check if it gets executed before the time?  Something like a 5000 ms

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my answer, what it does without the lambda is delay the window appearing

Comment: The index number is incorrect, it should be `randint(0,4)`, it will otherwise return `IndexError`

Comment: Oops, that was a rookie error, thanks for pointing it out